# Find maximum number according to this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Bob had N colors with him, all arranged in a straight line. He was interested in picking up a particular subarray of colors.

A pre-set is a set that contains all subarrays of colors that start from the first color and do not contain the last color.

An end-set is a set that contains all subarrays of colors that end at the last color and do not contain the first color.

He follow following steps now :

1. Choose the longest subarray that is contained in both pre-set as well as end-set.
2. rite that number in list L.
3. Delete the last color and apply the same procedure till only first color remains.

Now He will have N numbers which he has written in list L.We need to find maximum number in that list.

**Example** : Let N=4 nand array be [1,2,1,2] then here answer is 2.

**Explanation** :

The pre-sets for given array :  {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}

The end-sets for given array : {2, 1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2}

The common sets in both these sets : {1, 2}

The set with maximum number of elements  : {1, 2}

The length of this set is 2.So 2 will get added to list.

==============================================================

Now delete the last number from array, we get {1, 2, 1}

The pre-sets for {1, 2, 1} : {1}, {1, 2}

The end-sets for {1, 2, 1} : {2, 1}, {1}

The common sets in both these sets are : {1}

The set with maximum number of elements : {1}

The length of this set is 1. So 1 will get added to list.

=============================================================

Now delete the last number from array, we get {1, 2}

The pre-sets for {1, 2} : {1}

The end-sets for {1,2} : {2}

The common sets in both these sets : NULL . The set with maximum number of elements is --

The length of this set is 0. So 0 will get added to list.

Now printing maximum of list [2, 1, 0] = 2

N can be upto 10^6. So I can't repeat this whole procedure again and again. Is their better way to do it ?

Comment: use DP or memoization..

Comment: memoization = not recalculating things that have been calculated.. mostly using associative array to store previous answers
| 
DP = split problem into subproblem that easy enough to calculate then combine the answers,mostly using recursion
 | 

how = is to wide, depends on the programming language you're using

Comment: @Kokizzu I know these terms